# Dependency injection using Dagger 2

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I have a doubt regarding Dagger 2.

I have a BaseFragment class in which i am writing AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this), and all my fragments are extending from this Fragment class. I also have a FragmentBuilder class where i mention all the Fragments using @ContributesAndroidInjector annotation where i need injection to happen.

My doubt is, if in a Fragment i don’t need any dependency still i have to mention it in my FragmentBuilder class because its extending from BaseFragment. Is it a all right to do so or this will lead to any memory leak or is this a wrong design pattern ?

Please help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation i'll go with 2 "base" fragments, the first `BaseFragment` doesn't allow injection then you make a `BaseInjectableFragment` that inherit from the first one and you make it injectable, this looks more cleaner this way.

Comment: Great, that's one solution but can you also tell what are the consequences if i declare the Fragment in FragmentBuilder class but don't inject any dependency there. Does it leaks memory or anything ?

Comment: no you won't leak anything and nothing is injected till you add a `@Inject` annotation somewhere